# Database value repeatation error

Tags: java, database

When i was trying to run the following code it add the values repeatedly in each run.I need only.How can i maintain that using query.Here i inserting some values into my database with the help of another database(values for table name).My motive is to look for the new changes in the table.Not all the values in the table.

Code for reference:

```
 connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();
        String qry = "SELECT studentName From batcha "; 

        stmt = (PreparedStatement)  connection.prepareStatement(qry);    
        rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String check=new String(rs.getString(("studentName")));
                String student = check.replaceAll("\\s","");

                String userQry = "SELECT user_name From users "; 
                stmt1=connection.prepareStatement(userQry);
                rs1=stmt1.executeQuery();

                System.out.println(student+"ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");

                while(rs1.next()){

                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);

                String fclty=new String(rs1.getString(("user_name")));
                String fcltyog = fclty.replaceAll("\\s","");

                String sql1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+student+"(fcltyName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

                newStmt=(PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql1); 
                System.out.println(fcltyog+"fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
                newStmt.setString(1, fclty);
                newStmt.setInt(2, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(3, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(4, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(5, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(6, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(7, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(8, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(9, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(10, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(11, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(12, 0);
                newStmt.setInt(13, 0);

                newStmt.executeUpdate();

            newStmt.close();
```

Thanks in advance

:deepthi

Comment: can u tell me any `IF NOT EXIST` Queries for this?

Comment: Can you edit your question with some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one status column(value can be NEW, OLD) in table from DB1 and select rows with status as NEW, insert in the other database, update status of selected rows to OLD.

You have to do this repeatedly, may be in a loop at fixed intervals.